# Install Scrapy on Mac OS X error SSL pip

Tags: python, macos, scrapy, pip

Good, I am currently trying to install Scrapy in my MacOS but everything is problems, the first thing I introduce in terminal is:

```
pip install scrapy
```

And it returns me:

```
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
Collecting Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/twisted/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
```

Seeing the consideration that makes of updating, I realize it ...

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And it returns me the following:

```
You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.7.egg
```

The truth is that yesterday I was doing a thousand tests and gave me another type of error:

```
"SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed"
```

But this last mistake no longer shows me.

Comment: could you try installing into a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) ?

Comment: @elRuLL nop If I do that it gives me an error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] if I try install virtuales

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily (just for this module), you could manually install it. Download it from wherever you can, extract it if it is zipped then use `python setup.py install`

Comment: If I do that it gives me an error: Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/service_identity/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/service_identity/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!

And more errors similar.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this on MacOS, it is installing ***incremental*** before scrapy.

Source:
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2808